# Send an outlook appointment with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, email, outlook, appointment

I need to send an appointment with user default email client (in this case is outlook only), the user must have open your outlook, I can send it from local program, but when it is on server side, I have errors because the code is without To (because is with user default email client) only From

```
public void aAppointment(string subject, string body, string date, string start, string end, string location, string attend)
{
    Outlook._NameSpace ns = null;     
    Outlook.Application apptApp = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.AppointmentItem appt =
    apptApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem) as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
    ns = apptApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    ns.Logon(null, null, false, false);
    apptApp.ActiveWindow();
    appt.MeetingStatus = Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;
    appt.Subject = subject;
    appt.Body = body;
    appt.AllDayEvent = false;
    appt.Start = DateTime.Parse(date + " " + start);
    appt.Location = location;
    appt.End = DateTime.Parse(date + " " + end);    
    appt.RequiredAttendees = attend;
    appt.Display(false);
}
```

try in local enviroment an its Ok, open the new outlook appointment but in server enviroment have authentication error, the server have outlook, but I think that error is because not have credentials for final user machine

Thx for your answers

Comment: Using Office Interop on a server environment is a bad idea, no wonder you're having a headache.

Comment: Jeje its true, what is a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook, just like any Office app, cannot be used i na service (such as IIS). Create a MIME message with the content type of "text/calendar" and send the iCal data using straight SMTP.